# PHPExcel error while printed 2013

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExel 1.8 to read a template and fill some data in the template. I then generate the excel to be downloaded. The data is okay and the result is good. When I try to print the file, my Excel program become not responding. It crashed and give some error log :

```
Problem signature:

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH

Application Name:   EXCEL.EXE

Application Version:    15.0.4615.1000

Application Timestamp:  534ce2cc

Fault Module Name:  EXCEL.EXE

Fault Module Version:   15.0.4615.1000

Fault Module Timestamp: 534ce2cc

Exception Code: c0000005

Exception Offset:   0000000000807d48

OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48

Locale ID:  1057
```

It is the only error while printing the document generated by PHPExcel 1.8.

**UPDATE**:

I tried to open it and print it with Excel 2003 and it works perfectly. No problem at all. I think the problem is the PHPExcel maybe still have incompatibility with Excell 2013.

Comment: Just what I need..... a "guess the bug" type problem that I could spend the rest of my life looking for, and probably never find, let alone find a solution..... there are limits to the miracles that one man can achieve

Comment: What do you mean? Btw, I think the problem  is not with the PHPExcel, buat the excel 2013 itself. When I try to print it with excel 2003 it work like usual. So, I guess PHPExcel still not have some issue with the Excel 2013.

Comment: What I mean is that with a bug report saying that (in some cases, because it normally works perfectly well) printing via MS Excel 2013 doesn't work means that I need to try and identify a bug (which may even be in MS Excel 2013 or in a Windows print driver itself rather than in PHPExcel) which I first need to be able to replicate myself (and all my test documents print without problems).... that could be a lifetime's work just trying to replicate the problem, with no guarantee that I would be able to replicate it myself

Comment: If you want to replicate, I can give you the excel file. The function I use is quite simple. I just read the file and save it to php output. I don't even manipulate the content. In Excel 2013, it display nice but getting error when I try to print it. When I click print, the Excel just stopped working and the program closed. It seems strange because the function is very simple and it display nicely. Btw, thank you for your hard work to develop such great library. I just view your profile and you are the person behind PHPOffice. Sorry I don't recognize you before.

Comment: @Bharata, so, why don't you update your question with all relevant answers so anyone could replicate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for this crash could be with enabling compatibility for Office 2003.

Remove the following line for generating my file:

```
$objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);
```